# Mobile apps used just for authentication to a web site

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have an app that is no longer being used once you are logged in. The authenticated experience is limited to just one page which is in fact a redirect to another system. In effect, the app just logs you in. From there, we use webviews.

We want to remove the webview portion now - it's causing some issues on ux.

We are thinking of making the login screen pass credentials securely to a web browser which then authenticates you in and sends you to your proper destination.

Can a mobile app just be for authentication? This seems like it's going to violate the rules of why you have an app in the first place.

This is a "work around". Thoughts? Will Google/IOS TOS - reject this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Will Google/IOS TOS - reject this?` that's impossible for anyone to answer here

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to pass off authentication to the browser like that in Android.  It works with a webview only because the same process owns both and can override the cookies.  There isn't a way to do that for a browser.

You could possibly do something like putting the authentication token in the get parameters of the URL.  I wouldn't recommend it though, it could be insecure.  Anyone who has access to the URLs visited would be able to to use their token to mimic them.

Honestly I really wonder: Why do you even have an app?  If you're redirecting to your website, just have them use your website.